# How to go back to the results of :Gblame after selecting a particular commit?

Tags: git, vim, vim-plugin, git-blame

From the README of the [fugitive](https://github.com/tpope/vim-fugitive) plugin for vim:

> :Gblame brings up an interactive vertical split with git blame output.
>   Press enter on a line to edit the commit where the line changed, or o
>   to open it in a split.

Is it possible to go back to the blame output once I pressed enter on a particular commit?

Comment: Do you know you are going to return back to the blame? If so you should be using `o` instead of `<cr>` to view the commit

Comment: @Peter: ok. Can you add this as an answer?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

<strike>I think what you may be looking for is `-`</strike>

Edit: What you actually want are `O` and `o` instead of `<CR>` if you know you will be going back to the commit.

Here are all the flags for the `:Gblame` command:

> ```
>                                            *fugitive-:Gblame*
> :Gblame [flags] 
>  Run git-blame on the file and open the results in a
>  scroll bound vertical split. You can give any of
>  ltfnsewMC as flags and they will be passed along to
>  git-blame. The following maps, which work on the
>  cursor line commit where sensible, are provided:
>
>      g? show this help
>      A resize to end of author column
>      C resize to end of commit column
>      D resize to end of date/time column
>      q close blame and return to blamed window
>      gq q, then |:Gedit| to return to work tree version
>      <CR> q, then open commit
>      o open commit in horizontal split
>      O open commit in new tab
>      - reblame at commit
>      ~ reblame at [count]th first grandparent
>      P reblame at [count]th parent (like HEAD^[count])
> ```

For more information about the commands for `Fugitive`, look [here](https://github.com/tpope/vim-fugitive/blob/master/doc/fugitive.txt).

Comment: Nope. For me, `-` opens the previos commit from the file's log

Comment: Oh, are any of the other flags helpful? Because I think that is all there is for the `:Gblame` command.

Comment: I'm glad I was able to help, even though my initial suggestion was incorrect. I'll edit the answer for future people with the same question

Answer (score 1):

**Another option- go to previous buffer using mere vim commands:**

Since pressing 'enter' in vim-fugitive opens a new vim buffer on top of the old one- you can simply use vim command to go back:

```
:b 1
```

(go to buffer no. 1).

If already have too many opened buffers, you can list them:

```
:buffers
```

Comment: The problem is that `:G blame` results in _two_ buffers in a vertical split: one with the blame information alongside (and scroll-bound to) the buffer with the file contents. `:b 1` restores only one of those two buffers.